# icloud connect A0 BAD Parse Error

Tags: jakarta-mail, icloud

Code using to connect:

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
String host = "imap.mail.me.com";
int port = 993;

String result = null;
TestLogger.log("Connecting to Imap..");
try {
    //Connect to the server

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
    session.setDebug(true);
    Store store = session.getStore();
    store.connect(host, port, "username","pass");
```

The store.connect throws A0 BAD Parse Error, full debug output:

```
Attempt #0
Connecting to Imap..

DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imap.mail.me.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK 
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: ATOKEN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=imap.mail.me.com, user=<user>, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A0 BAD Parse Error
***** ERROR *****: Error
***** ERROR *****: javax.mail.MessagingException: A0 BAD Parse Error;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A0 BAD Parse Error
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:668)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at
```

Comment: Upgrade your [JavaMail version](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).

Comment: If that doesn't help, set the `mail.debug.auth` property to `true` to get the complete protocol exchange in the debug output (but don't post it here!).  Send that debug output to javamail_ww@oracle.com if you need more help.

Comment: Upgrading javamail library helped.